# Inconsistency between server response size and client blob object size

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html

I've an ASP.NET MVC application that in one page it has a button that when the user click the button in the web browser:

1. the browser sends an AJAX POST to the server
2. the server creates a ZIP archive using *MemoryStream* so there’s no physical file in the server
3. the server returns the ZIP archive in the response’s body
4. the browser gets the response body and creates a BLOB object which is     downloaded by the user

Until step 3 everything is working as expected. I have used Fiddler to intercept the server’s response, I created manually a ZIP file with the bytes from the response, and it is OK.

**When the user download the file from the web browser it is corrupt. I have realized that the size (length) of the file is bigger than the length of the response’s body.**

Here’s the code that generates the response from the server

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.zip");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", memoryStream.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip; charset=utf-8");
Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
Response.End();
```

Here’s the code that create and download the file from the server’s response

```
saveZipFile = (zipFile: any /* zipFile is the server's response */) => {
    if (!('Blob' in window)) {
        alert('Your browser does not support the HTML5 Blob.');
        return;
    }

    var fileName = "test.zip";
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([zipFile], { encoding: "UTF-8", type: "application/zip; charset=utf-8" } as any);

    if ('msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator) {
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileName);
    } else {
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download File';
        if ('webkitURL' in window) {
            // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
            downloadLink.href = (window as any).webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        } else {
            // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
            downloadLink.onclick = (event: any) => {
                document.body.removeChild(event.target);
            };
            downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }

        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

If you need more details, please let me know.

What can be wrong?

PD: I think it’s related to string encoding.

Comment: I don't think you should do this Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", memoryStream.Length.ToString()); The browser usually send that header automatically